# shutdown hook code is not executing completely

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, java-threads

I have a Spring batch application and in shutdown hook i have add some peace of code which check if there is any batch is in running state and if that is is running  state close it gracefully it include DB calls as well , but problem is that peace of code is not executing completely.

Sometime it got stuck at 
log.info("************explorer.getJobInstanceCount(job.getName()) "+explorer.getJobInstanceCount(job.getName()));

and sometimes at  List jobInstances = explorer.findJobInstancesByJobName(job.getName(), 0, explorer.getJobInstanceCount(job.getName()));

explorer.getJobInstanceCount and explorer.findJobInstancesByJobName method are making DB calls to get the details  from batch metadata table.

I am running this on the UNIX machine and environment is Dev. This is not the complete code i have to do other stuff after this but i am not able to proceed as i am not able to get the hold of currently running job if any.

In the log can see

[Thread-3] JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
[Thread-3] JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(*) from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ?]

but there is nothing after that .

Comment: Last time I used `ShutdownHook`, it was noted that there is no guarantee that it will execute completely and that it generally shouldn't contain any "slow" code. I am a bit confused what is it that you are trying to achieve? Does this hook actually do anything other than just logging what is still running?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please edit to include some indication of where the code stops executing, as well as your dev environment (your own machine, Heroku, etc.). Your code may be exiting for reasions related to the OS and not the code itself.

Comment: @DeepakPal And that's the problem - DB calls take too much time. How do you shut down your JVM? You could work around the shutdown hooks limitations by e.g. creating a rest endpoint that would stop all running jobs (and prevent starting new ones) and shut down JVM only once this step is completed.

Comment: @DeepakPal Does the app has UI? If so, you can add a stop button somewhere. Or does it accept user input while running? If so, you can add a new command that will shut it down when typed.

Comment: As shutdown hooks are for short cleanups you may consider using a Spring `ApplicationListener` acting a `ContextClosedEvent`.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak there is no UI  its back-end application.

Comment: @ArneBurmeister i did try calling  ApplicationListener  but its never get invoked .